# Test if matrix object exists in TCL

Tags: tcl, exists

I want to test if a [tcl-matrix](https://www.tcl.tk/community/tcl2004/Tcl2003papers/kupries-doctools/tcllib.doc/struct/matrix.html) object exists. How can I do that?

Following code isn't working.

```
package require struct::matrix

# Test (now we expect 0)
info exists m
# Create the object
struct::matrix m

# Test again, now I expect 1, however it returns 0!!!
info exists m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`info commands`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M9) to test for the existence of a matrix object. [`info exists`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M14) tests for the (non-)existence of variables.

```
% package req struct::matrix
2.0.3
% info commands m
% struct::matrix m
::m
% info commands m
m
```

### Background

A matrix object is implemented as a Tcl command (an alias command, to be precise) plus per-matrix Tcl namespace (as storage).

Alternatively, but this depends to much on the current implementation, you may test for the existence of a so-named namespace:

```
% package req struct::matrix
2.0.3
% namespace exists m
0
% struct::matrix m
::m
% namespace exists m
1
```

Testing for the command will also keep working when a matrix object becomes re-implemented as a TclOO object, for instance.

Comment: Is there a reasonable way to ask a command if it is a `struct::matrix` or are we talking duck typing here?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of poking through [the struct::matrix source code](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/5d1ae3a8ae4efa67):

```
% package req struct::matrix
2.0.3
% set m [struct::matrix]
::matrix1
% expr {$m in [interp aliases]}
1
% string first MatrixProc [interp alias {} $m]
18
% proc is_matrix {name} {
    expr {
         $name in [interp aliases] &&
         [string first MatrixProc [interp alias {} $name]] != -1
    }
}
% is_matrix $m
1
```

If you use the `struct::matrix m` form, then instead of `$m`, use the fully qualified `::m`

```
% struct::matrix m
::m
% is_matrix m
0
% is_matrix ::m
1
```

Comment: Clearly, this requires knowledge of the *current implementation* of struct::matrix. If it changes in some future tcllib release, this answer becomes invalid.